# How can i stretch a div across the entire width of a page?

Tags: css, html

I'm attempting to make a div flush with the left, right, and top of the page but i can't seem to manage it. I've attempted multiple solutions that other people stated but i cannot for the life of me figure it out! If anyone could help it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show us some code, please!

Comment: How strange! By default DIVs appear across the entire width of a browser. So what's your problem? Why not include some code to show ONE of your solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably just not removing the `margin` on `<body>`.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

or the first element inside of of the `<div>` has some `margin`.

Your widths will be `auto` off the bat, which will appear to be 100%, but allow you to add padding and margins without worry if you're using the default box model.

Comment: Well thought of... +1 for that. Perhaps you can add to this that padding of BODY should be 0 as well. And also it would be a good idea to set the margins of DIV to 0.

Comment: @itsols You only need to do it for the body or as Bill said for the `div` its inside if that's the case. Here is an example, feel free to put this in your answer Bill. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6j4y6/)